# Using ActiveMQ destionaions (on startup) in java application

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jndi

I have configured a number of destinations to be available at startup in ActiveMQ conf/activemq.xml. I can see that queues and topics have been created on ActiveMQ web console. Now I want to use the same queues and topics for message exchange through my Java program using JMS. Below is the code I am using. However, I cannot see any message en queued on the Topic in ActiveMQ web console.

```
package com.test;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    Destination destination =null;
    String destinationName = "MyTopic";
    final int numMsgs;
    Context jndiContext = null;

    // producer details
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    //consumer details
    ConnectionFactory consumerConnectionFactory = null;
    Connection consumerConnection = null;
    Session consumerSession = null;
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer=null;

    /*
     * Create a JNDI API InitialContext object
     */
    try {
        jndiContext = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create JNDI API context: " + e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Look up connection factory and destination.
     */
    try {
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        destination = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(destinationName);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Create connection. Create session from connection; false means
     * session is not transacted. Create sender and text message. Send
     * messages, varying text slightly. Send end-of-messages message.
     * Finally, close connection.
     */
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            message.setText("This is message " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Sending message: " + message.getText());
            producer.send(message);

        }

        /*
         * Send a non-text control message indicating end of messages.
         */
        producer.send(session.createMessage());

        /***
         * to recieve message
         * */

        try {
            consumerConnectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            consumerConnection = consumerConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            consumerConnection.start();
            consumerSession = consumerConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            messageConsumer = consumerSession.createConsumer(destination);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String greeting = "NO_GREETING";

        // read a message from the topic destination
        Message recievedMessage = messageConsumer.receive();
        System.out.println("******************" + recievedMessage);
        // check if a message was received
        if (recievedMessage != null) {
            // cast the message to the correct type
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) recievedMessage;

            // retrieve the message content
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println(": received message with text='{}'" + text);

            // create greeting
            greeting = "Hello " + text + "!";
        } else {
            System.out.println(": no message received");
        }

        System.out.println("greeting={}" + greeting);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null && consumerConnection !=null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
                consumerConnection.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

My JNDI prop file

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

# use the following property to configure the default connector
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616/

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as. 
#connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = example.MyQueue


# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
topic.MyTopic = SOME.TOPIC
```

ActiveMQ configuration file inside  ActiveMQ/conf/activemq.xml file

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

     <destinations>
      <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR" />
      <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC" />
    </destinations>

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

In my output I can see below text.

```
Sending message: This is message 1
Sending message: This is message 2
```

However I believe that the message is not put on topic as no messages are showing en queued on ActiveMQ web console.

Can anyone help me to identify if it is the right way to access ActiveMQ destionation on startup in java. I am well aware how to create queues and topics through Java using JMS and ActiveMQ. But in this project I want to access exisiting queues and topics in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Topics require an active subscription in order to deliver a message otherwise the message is dropped, that is the nature of publish / subscribe.  If you want to send a message and read it later you should use a Queue, or as a last resort a Durable Topic Subscription.  There are plenty of tutorials on this if you bother to google a bit.